# Xamarin iOS c__AnonStorey1

Tags: ios, xamarin, mono

I retrieve this crash log about my app.

```
System.NullReferenceExceptionObject reference not set to an instance of an object
Raw TouristApp.PuntiEventiView.c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0()
Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply()
UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int, string[], intptr, intptr)(wrapper managed-to-native)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[] args, string principalClassName, string delegateClassName)
TouristApp.Application.Main(string[] args)
```

I have no clue about the error, in my class (PuntiEventiView) there is no call to c__AnonStorey1.m (it seems a Mono file).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your app step by step. You're using an anonymous delegate or lambda somewhere which causes a NULL ref exception.

The `c__AnonStorey1` is a compiler generated class which captures your local variables.

(Using my crystal ball here to guess, because you are not showing any code)

Comment: Thx for the response.
I can't debug step by step (the log was sent to Xamarin Insight), but now I have an idea. Thanks.
About the code:
It's a class that has 491 row and has various reference to other class, so I doubt the code of that class will be useful if I post it. :-)